# Can't get the desired speed from the Main Server

Tags: server, updates

I usually got 40-50 KB/s speed for downloading updates from Ubuntu Main Server. But for a while now, I'm not getting the desired speed. It's now came down to 4-5 KB/s. But when I switched to Server for Bangladesh (I'm a Bangladeshi), I got good speed (as of mentioned earlier). Now what's the problem here? Why I'm not getting the same speed as I used to get earlier?

Comment: Are you saying that the download speeds slowed when you changed from English to Bangladesh language selection or to a Bangladeshi download server? If servers I'm assuming its the CDN, bandwith, location of servers ect.

Comment: @wlraider70 No. I mean when I select the main server then the speed is slower than the Bangladesh server. It's not about language.